# Split array char got from Serial in Arduino IDE

Tags: java, c, string, char, arduino

Using Arduino IDE, I am trying to read a string from Serial and after I need to process it, separating some bytes from it. The string begins with `@` and terminates with `;`. The "parts" of the data are:

- byte 0: "@"
- bytes 1 to 3: section A, which is an integer
- bytes 3 to 6: section B, which is an integer
- bytes 7 to 63: section C, which is a float

For example, if I have the string `@002001100.0;`, section A is 002, section B is 001 and section C is 100.0.

For reading the entire string from Serial, I am doing

```
  char UsartBuffer = 0;
  char UsartString[64];

  boolean commandReceived = false;
  if (Serial.available() >0) {
    UsartBuffer = Serial.read();
    UsartString[0] = UsartBuffer;
    int counter = 0;

    if (UsartBuffer == '@'){
      while (UsartBuffer != ';'){
        if (Serial.available() >0){
          UsartBuffer = Serial.read();
          if (UsartBuffer != ' '){
            counter++;
            UsartString[counter] = UsartBuffer;
          }
        }

      }
      UsartString[counter+1]='\0';
      commandReceived = true;
    }
  }
```

For splitting the strings I did

```
char* getClass(String command){
  char returnStr[3];
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    returnStr[i] = command[i+1];
  }
  return returnStr;
}

char* getSubClass(String command){
  char returnStr[3];
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    returnStr[i] = command[i+4];
  }
  return returnStr;
}

char* getDataValue(String command){
  char returnStr[56];
  int lastByte = 56;
  for (int i=0; i<56; i++){
    if (command[i+7]==';'){
      lastByte = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < lastByte; i++) returnStr[i] = command[i+7];
  for (int i = lastByte; i < 56; i++) returnStr[i] = '/0';
  return returnStr;
}
```

And when I did

```
if (commandReceived){
  Serial.println(UsartString);
  Serial.println(getClass(UsartString));
  Serial.println(getSubClass(UsartString));
  Serial.println(getDataValue(UsartString));
}
```

I got the even strange results:

```
@002000107.0;
a

!œ
107.0Ñ
```

Thus, also, what did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be due to `getClass()`, `getSubClass()` and `getDataValue()` returning local variables (`returnStr`). As soon as the functions return these values will be lost.

A few ways to avoid this:

Return a `String` object (a local `String` will get copied on the way out of the functions):

```
String getClass(String command) {
    String returnStr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        returnStr += command[i+1];
    }

    return returnStr;
}
```

Dynamically allocate the `char*` within the functions (using `malloc()`) - if you do this you'll need to be careful to deallocate it afterwards (using `free()`):

```
char* getClass(String command) {
    size_t length = 3;
    char* returnStr = (char*) malloc(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        returnStr[i] = command[i+1];
    }

    return returnStr;
}

// Usage
char* classStr = getClass(UsartString);
Serial.println(classStr);
free(classStr);
```

Pass a pre-allocated `char` array into the functions - this can be a local variable in the calling function:

```
void getClass(String command, char* returnStr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        returnStr[i] = command[i+1];
    }

    return returnStr;
}

// Usage
char returnStr[3];
getClass(UsartString, returnStr);
Serial.println(returnStr);
```